# blank page when added bootstrap to styles.css, remove bootstrap and I get login page

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have no errors or anything in terminal just a blank page, nothing wrong in developer tools. I couldn't find anything anywhere else regarding this issue either. I appreciate any tips thank you.

styles.css: I remove this and my login html template is displayed

```
@import 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

login.component.html:

```
<!--login modal-->
<div id="loginModal" class="modal show" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h1 class="text-center">Login</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form class="form col-md-12 center-block">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Sign In</button>
                <span class="pull-right"><a href="#">Register</a></span><span><a href="#">Need help?</a></span>
              </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="col-md-1accordion2">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

app.component.html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app-routing-module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/register/register.component';
import { UserComponent } from './components/user/user.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
component files
  {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
  {path: 'user/management', component: UserComponent }, 
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' }  

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http'; 
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthInterceptor } from './interceptor/auth.interceptor';
import { NotificationModule } from './notification.module';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/register/register.component';
import { UserComponent } from './components/user/user.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    UserComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NotificationModule,
   
  ],
  providers: [ 
   {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,useClass: AuthInterceptor,multi:true}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate your problem?

Comment: My html disappears as soon as i add the bootstrap in styles.css

Comment: Try to include your css file in index.html file instead of import.

**<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">**

Comment: I get this in dev tools: Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: Go to styles.css under the root directory of your angular app. Add this line at the top
**@import url('https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');** to resolve MIME issue.

Comment: Imports in `.scss` only make sense, if you are importing `.scss` that you can for instance use defined variables later on. If you want to import a `.css` file in your angular project, just add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">` to your index file or use the appropriate position in your `angular.json` (depending on the seed project you are using) -- e.g., for @angular/cli in the `"styles"` section. Have a [look here](https://medium.com/@davembush/adding-css-and-javascript-to-an-angular-cli-project-2b843a8283f3).

Comment: I get this now: Failed to compile.

./src/styles.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./src/styles.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Error: Failed to find 'unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
  in [
    /Users/nathanadavis/Downloads/BugTracker/frontend/BugTrackerApp/src
  ]
    at /Users/nathanadavis/Downloads/BugTracker/frontend/BugTrackerApp/node_modules/postcss-import/lib/resolve-id.js:35:13
    at async Promise.all (index 0)

Comment: Did you add https before your url unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css?